# Generic RPM that can install on any os - error: RPM is for a different operating system

Tags: rpm, packaging

How can I make a rpm from a spec file that can be installed on any host? Currently I have a spec file  but when installing the rpm on other hosts I get this:

```
package my_software-1.0-1dist is for a different operating system
```

The files in the rpm are just perl programs so if the system has perl and some modules which are already spelled out on requires lines I shouldn't need to check the os. I already have BuildArch: noarch in my RPM.

Answer (score 2):

Technically you can't. The OS the package was built for is encoded as part of the RPM header and there's no way to specify "any" as an OS. You can change `%_os` to another OS when building, but there's no generic value.

```
$ rpm -q --qf '%{os}\n' setup
linux
```

Comment: Although "you can't" is definitely an answer im disappointed RPM doesnt provide for this. I'll wait for a while to see if anyone else responds before accepting this answer.